# No module named '' while using reload

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to reload a module in real-time without exit the program:

```
import test

def ClickButton(self): # Testing purposes
   reload(test)
```

The error:

```
No module named 'test'
```

There's a solution without pre-compiled the source (py -> pyc)? Because my files connects between them on a folder /test and not on /lib (folder from python)

Thanks!

Comment: Is test a folder or a .py script?

Comment: A .py script, not a folder

Comment: And it is in the same directory?

Comment: Yes they are, they are in the same folder: game